# Differenze di uso tra "i fili" e "le fila"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/filo1/) afferma che il plurale di "il filo" è "i fili", ma, con valore collettivo e in locuzioni particolari, è anche "le fila". Potreste spiegarmi quali sono le principali differenze di uso tra "i fili" e "le fila"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ciao,

> “Le fila del partito.” D’onde viene questo strano plurale? Vediamo.
>   Esiste un sostantivo femminile singolare la fila, serie di persone o cose più o meno allineate una dietro l’altra, che ha un plurale regolare le file. Diciamo perciò che davanti ai negozi si formano lunghe file (oggi è più in uso code), e che i militari rompono le file (oppure le righe), cioè rompono il loro allineamento.
>
> Esiste poi un secondo sostantivo, ma di genere maschile, il filo, propriamente il prodotto della filatura (un filo di lana, di cotone). Ecco il colpevole! Filo ha due plurali: uno regolare maschile, i fili, e uno irregolare femminile, le fila. Perché mai? Perché il nome d’origine, in latino, è neutro: filum singolare, fila plurale, e accanto al nostro plurale regolare fili è sopravvissuta anche la forma originale latina fila. La quale, mancando in italiano il genere neutro, si è rifugiata nel femminile.
>
> Ciò premesso, il plurale più comune è quello regolare, i fili: “i fili del telegrafo”, “tre fili di perle”. Il plurale femminile le fila è d’uso più limitato: si incontra in senso collettivo, per indicare molti fili presi insieme: abbiamo così “le fila dell’ordito”, e diciamo che il formaggio fuso “fa le fila”; ma più spesso lo incontriamo in frasi figurate, come “le fila della congiura”, “le fila del partito”, “tenere in pugno le fila del movimento”.

Questa definizione è la più facilmente comprensibile a mio parere.

Ti rimando alla fonte della mia risposta: [Fonte Corriere della Sera](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/F/fili.shtml?refresh_ce-cp)

Comment: Grazie mille, @Tru3F0x, ma cosa significano "le fila del partito", "le fila della congiura” e "tenere in pugno le fila del movimento”?

Comment: Esiste anche l'espressione "muovere le fila"?

Comment: "Tirare/Muovere le fila" ha significato figurativo che significa controllare e muovere a proprio piacimento qualcosa. Deriva dai fili di una spettacolo di marionette dove il marionettista controlla, attraverso i fili il movimento di ogni elemento sul palco.

Dire "tra le fila del partito" vuol dire "tra gli elementi del partito" (immaginati disposti in file ordinate)

Comment: Grazie @RiccardoI, ma per quello che hai spiegato delle "fila del partito", "file" non ha un significato diverso da "fili"?

Comment: È figurativo, come per i fili di un telaio tutti in ordine e allineati. Anche qui l'uso del plurale in "a" credo dipenda come detto da Tru3F0x dalla derivazione latina di filo.